# d3 second force layout to avoid text overlap

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to implement a force layout on D3 v4 with a large no. of nodes with labels. The problem is that the labels overlap and affects the readability. I found this example which is on v3 and implements something similar to what I want. How can I implement the same in v4?
http://bl.ocks.org/MoritzStefaner/1377729

```
var text = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "labels")
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("text")
    .attr("class", "dataLabels")
    .attr("font-size","6px")
    .attr("dx", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".15em");
```